# Is there a way to get TypeScript to correctly infer that an object's property is related to another?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a ModalContext in a React App to open dialog boxes, it takes an object with a component and props keys, and I want typescript to correctly infer that the props are the same as the component props, so I can get rid of the switch statement in the ModalComponent component:

```js
import { ComponentProps, createContext } from 'react';

import SelectYearModal from '@components/SelectYearModal';
import ChangeDefaultModal from '@components/ChangeDefaultModal';

const ModalComponents = {
    SelectYearModal: SelectYearModal,
    ChangeDefaultModal: ChangeDefaultModal,
};
export type ModalMap = typeof ModalComponents;

type ModalComponentProps<T extends keyof ModalMap> = ComponentProps<
    ModalMap[T]
>;
interface ModalState<T extends keyof ModalMap> {
    component: T;
    props: ModalComponentProps<T>;
}

type AnyModalState = {
    [K in keyof ModalMap]: ModalState<K>;
}[keyof ModalMap];

export type ModalType = AnyModalState | null;

export interface ModalContextValues {
    Modal: ModalType;
    setModal: (modal: ModalType) => void;
    loading: boolean;
    setLoading: (loading: boolean) => void;
}

export const ModalContext = createContext<ModalContextValues>({
    Modal: null,
    setModal: () => {},
    loading: false,
    setLoading: () => {},
});

export const ModalComponent = ({ modal }: { modal: ModalType }) => {
    if (!modal) return null;

    switch (modal.component) {
        case 'SelectYearModal':
            return <SelectYearModal {...modal.props} />;
        case 'ChangeDefaultModal':
            return <ChangeDefaultModal {...modal.props} />;
        default:
            return null;
    }
};
```

So I want to use something like this, so I don't have to use a switch statement:

```js
export const ModalComponent = ({ modal }: { modal: ModalType }) => {
    if (!modal) return null;

    const Modal = ModalComponents[modal.component];
    return <Modal {...modal.props} />;
};
```

However Typescript will throw an error because it thinks the props can be of any component in ModalComponents:

```
Argument of type 'SelectYearModalProps | ModalConfirmProps' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SelectYearModalProps & ModalConfirmProps'.
  Type 'ModalConfirmProps' is not assignable to type 'SelectYearModalProps & ModalConfirmProps'.
    Type 'ModalConfirmProps' is missing the following properties from type 'SelectYearModalProps': years, selectedYearIdx, setSelectedYearIdx
```

I wonder if there's a way to make Typescript correctly infer that the props will be the props of the corresponding component

Comment: can you add what your `ModalConfirmProps` and `SelectYearModalProps` looks like?

Answer (score 1):

not sure if this is what you're looking for, but would this suit your use case?

As per the additional requirement to have the prop types assigned dynamically this is the updated logic

```
type ComponenProps<T extends (...args: any[]) => any> = T extends (arg: infer A) => any ? A : never;

type FunctionsMap = typeof ModalComponents;

type UnionOfProps = keyof FunctionsMap extends infer K ?
  K extends keyof FunctionsMap ? ComponenProps<FunctionsMap[K]> : never
  : never;

type UnionToIntersection<U> = 
  (U extends any ? (x: U)=>void : never) extends ((x: infer I)=>void) ? I : never

type ModalProps = UnionToIntersection<UnionOfProps>

export const ModalComponent = ({ modal }: { modal: ModalType }) => {
    if (!modal) return null;
    const Modal = ModalComponents[modal.component];
    const props = modal.props as ModalProps;
    return <Modal {...props} />;
};
```

the UnionToIntersection type was reference from here: [Transform union type to intersection type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50374908/transform-union-type-to-intersection-type)

Comment: I'm not sure this is the best approach because I still have to keep adding all the possible prop types as new modal components are added

Comment: @JoãoPedro got it. in which case it might be a bit more complicated. Just updated my answer to reflect the additional requirement

Comment: @JoãoPedro you can probably get rid of the `FunctionsMap` and just use your `ModalMap in the `UnionOfProps`